# How to calculate whether certain fields are all not null?

Tags: postgresql

Say I have a table "articles" with the columns "author", "title" (nullable) and "body" (nullable). When I query this table, I want to get a fourth column: A boolean value that says whether the "title" and "body" are both set. How can I do this with Postgres?

I don't want this fourth column to be stored. I want it to be dynamically computed, so I was hoping I could do something like:

```
SELECT author, title, body, ALL(title, body) AS is_complete FROM articles;
```

I cannot find any way to accomplish this. Does anyone have any pointers?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for `IS NULL`

```
SELECT author, 
       title, 
       body, 
       title is not null and body is not null as is_complete 
FROM articles;
```

Another way of doing this is to concatenate the two columns. If either one is `null` the result will also be null (or the other way round: the result of the concatenation will only be not null if both are not null):

```
SELECT author, 
       title, 
       body, 
       title||body is not null is_complete 
FROM articles;
```

If you want to treat empty values (`''`) the same as a `NULL` value you need to use something like:

```
SELECT author, 
       title, 
       body, 
       coalesce(title,'') = '' and coalesce(body,'') = '' as is_complete 
FROM articles;
```

If you need this very often you could create a view based on this query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `IS NOT NULL` on row expressions, like:

```
SELECT author, title, body, ROW(title, body) IS NOT NULL AS is_complete FROM articles;
```

Per [spec](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparison.html), it means:

> If the *expression* is row-valued, then `IS NULL` is true when the row expression itself is null or when all the row's fields are null, **while `IS NOT NULL` is true when the row expression itself is non-null and all the row's fields are non-null**.
>
> (...)
>
> This definition conforms to the SQL standard, and is a change from the inconsistent behavior exhibited by PostgreSQL versions prior to 8.2.

Answer (score -2):

You can use **case when** statement also

```
SELECT author, 
       title, 
       body, 
       case when title is not null and body is not null then 1 else 0 end as is_complete 
FROM articles;
```